# What is the に doing in「略語は社内での使用に留(とど)めましょう。」?

Tags: grammar, verbs, particle-に

This phrase is a heading in a business-Japanese book. Underneath, the book talks about avoiding casual contracted words in the office and on phone calls.

From what I know about 留める(とどめる), which is a transitive verb, I would think 「...**を**留めましょう」 would be correct here. Although I can find examples of 「...に留める」, I can't find any that, to me, would make sense here. What does 「...に留める」 mean in this context?

Comment: The direct object here is 略語, whose を was overridden by the topic marker は, whereas 社内での使用 is a destination (“confine the use of abbreviations *to* in-company use”).

Comment: Ahh, so the distinction in the sentence (and also thanks to sundowner's answer) is about confining abbreviations to INTERNAL use. That's the piece I was missing. I guess I assumed that companies prefer avoiding abbreviations even internally, but my assumption overrode my reading abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to understand it is to think that これを is omitted.

So verbosely, the sentence says

> 略語(について)は、これを社内での使用に留{とど}めましょう,

which literally means

> Regarding abbreviations, let's keep this to internal use.

---

It is fairly common to move objects to the front this way.

- この本はもう読み終えた I finished reading this book.
- 必要なものは買った I bought necessary things.

---

The famous [Article 9 of the Japanese Constitution](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E5%9B%BD%E6%86%B2%E6%B3%95%E7%AC%AC9%E6%9D%A1) has the following:

> 第九条　**日本国民は**、正義と秩序を基調とする国際平和を誠実に希求し、国権の発動たる**戦争と、武力による威嚇又は武力の行使は**、国際紛争を解決する手段としては、**永久にこれを放棄する**。
> ②　前項の目的を達するため、陸海空軍その他の戦力は、これを保持しない。国の交戦権は、これを認めない。

A literal translation of the bold part would be

> The Japanese people, regarding war and threat or use of forces, renounce these forever.